# How to remove SID (session ID) from URL in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, url, session

How to remove the **session ID** from the URL in Magento 2 (frontend). This is the `SID` query parameter in the URL.

For example: [https://example.com/contact/?SID=sfl317buq8ru4uf4a...](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147373/)

***Removed starting from 2.3.3*** https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25663

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Go to the *Store > Configuration > General > Web > Session Validation Settings > Use SID on Storefront* and set its value to No

[image: example]

Here is the [good answer about the SID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300200/magento-sid-u-appearing-in-some-urls):

> The SID is a "session ID". Magento uses this to track a user's
>   activity within the same Magento installation. Normally, Magento
>   powers one website and one store from one installation (database).
>
> Magento could power multiple websites with multiple stores from one
>   installation though. The SID allows users to stay logged in while
>   navigating across these websites/stores.
>
> I think if you have the function enabled, the SID is sent when
>   accessing catalog URLs so Magento can update the session with the
>   user's location/state for the current website/store.
>
> If you're not running a multi-website or multi-store environment, it's
>   safe to disable the SID on the frontend.

Comment: Thanks for reply !!! I go do this and reply the result in a few minutes !!!

Comment: I've used this approach and disabled SID on the front-end, also Single-store mode set to "Yes", the SID still shows up. In production mode, should we regeneration files to make this work? I don't think so since it's a config value. Any ideas?

Comment: @dchayka I think this might be a cache issue. Try to refresh it.

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau cache has been refreshed. I figured out what it is. Thank you for following up.

Comment: @SiarheyUchukhlebau How Can I change the meta tag for example.com/?SID=nufp7tmaardcoff2ddbp4vmmo6 in magento 2??

Comment: @supriyamishra If you want to rewrite the 'SID' parameter, you should overwrite the `SESSION_ID_QUERY_PARAM` in the `vendor/magento/framework/Session/SidResolverInterface.php` in some way. You can see how it is implemented in the `Magento\Framework\Session\SidResolver` class.

Comment: @supriyamishra What was your solution to get rid of the SID in url? I have changed the Magento 2 setting, but still SID is in URL.

Comment: @Webninja did you clean a cache?

Comment: Yes, that I did, but it did not help.

Comment: Disable session.use_trans_sid setting in php.ini

Answer (score 5):

Those of you who already set *Use SID on Storefront* to *No* (as Siarhey Uchukhlebau pointed out in his answer) but still can't get rid of **&sid=...** in the URL, check out following links.

It is a Magento Bug, which will be fixed in version 2.3
Related ticket: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9453

Fortunately, there is a Inchoo Tutorial on how to remove it via .htaccess file as workaround
http://inchoo.net/dev-talk/remove-sid-from-magento-urls/

Comment: Magento 2.3 is released. Has this been fixed? Can't find anything about it.

Comment: I'm not using Magento 2.3, but in Magento 2.2.6 I'm not facing this issue anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't `?SID` automatically added by PHP if PHP is configured to not store sessions on the server or the browser doesn't accept cookies?

I believe Magento doesn't do this by default. There is a setting for it, but I'm assuming that the OP didn't change this, otherwise he would have figured this out by himself.

Comment: If the PHP run-time option session.use_trans_sid is enabled, relative URIs will be changed to contain the session id automatically. This option is not on by default.

Magento 2's default setting for "Use SID on Storefront" is "Yes".

Answer (score 0):

Use Frontend SID removed from store configuration settings from a Magento update. 
However the value may still be set to 1 in the core_config_data table.

Update your MySQL database table 'core_config_data' and set the value to '0' for path 'web/session/use_frontend_sid'. Do this for all store values.

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = '0' WHERE path = 'web/session/use_frontend_sid';
```

Answer (score -6):

`vendor/magento/framework/Session/SidResolver.php`

Find the function and comment the line as below.

```
public function getUseSessionInUrl()
{
   // return $this->_useSessionInUrl;
}
```

Comment: Don't edt Magento core files. Also after the next Composer command, the contents of `vendor/magento/framework/` might get restored/updated