# Suddenly started using another logged in user's session - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, security, session, customer-session

This might be too broad of a question but it is a gigantic security issue and I have no idea where to start debugging this.

I was testing some features on my dev server while someone else was logged in on the frontend as well. At one point after refreshing I saw that I was suddenly logged in as the other user's account, I did not even know which email they were using and had never logged in with that account before but I could now do everything from change his password to place orders with his account.

As far as I know I'm not doing anything weird with sessions, but the most likely place I could see this going wrong is a Helper class that is used in various places but that is only used for getting the current user's customer group ID.

It is a fairly standard and clean Magento 2.1.9 installation on a LAMP stack, we started developing two weeks ago so we have one custom module that we are working on right now and no third party modules.

Comment: It could be a cache issue. Confirm it by going through the checkout. You will not actually order as the other account.

Comment: I tried and I was able to actually place the orders and change their account information

Comment: As Fabian already mentioned: This can be a cache issue (do you use varnish?) or also a session problem. If the session lifetime is very long a session collission can occur.  Apart from this I think you need to update your question with some more technical information to get some good answers and help here.

Comment: I do not use varnish, the sessions lifetime is a couple of minutes and at most 2 people log in at a time so I don't think it's a session collission.

I have updated the question with some information about the version and modules, what other information would be useful to share? I'm not really sure what could cause this so I don't know what might be relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to replicate this issue by clicking a link with a "SID" (session ID) in it. If that session ID belonged to another customer and they were logged in, I could see their details.

Because the site I was working on was a single website/store (no multi-website/store) I could stop the issue by changing:

Store > Configuration > General > Web > Session Validation Settings > "Use SID on Storefront" == "No"

You may need to wipe your session store to ensure no customers are still sharing sessions.

I found this related question useful and it contains more info over there:

[How to Remove SID (SESSION_ID) from URL in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147373/how-to-remove-sid-session-id-from-url-in-magento-2)

Comment: You're right, thanks, this seems to be the most likely reason since we were sharing urls