# why I take session of other customer

Tags: magento2, customer-session

I have a problem with a Magento2 installation.

If I am logged in as a client on a browser, with another browser (client not logged in). If I do the same actions on both browsers, the second browser (on which I was not connected) takes the first session ....

I Try this solution : 
[Suddenly started using another logged in user's session - Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195067/suddenly-started-using-another-logged-in-users-session-magento-2)

But It doesn't work

SID is disabled

I have the problem that the cache is enabled or disabled

And I still have the problem if session are stored on files or on db

After some modifications, it seems that the session is no longer "stolen". By cons there is always a problem in the display. For example with my logged session I go to https://example.com/customer/account/ as well as with my unlogged session at the same time: on the unlogged session I see the information of the other session.

I'm thinking of a cache problem, but by completely disabling the cache :

```
php bin/magento cache:disable
```

the problem persists

someone would have an idea of the origin of the problem?

It seem's that is a server issue, on my chrome console I've got this message :

```
Error parsing header X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block, 1; mode=block: expected semicolon at character position 13. The default protections will be applied.
```

Comment: You have issue in login Magento admin at a time same user with multiple browser Right ?

Comment: @KirtiNariya no the issue takes place on the frontend side. I am connected as a customer on a browser and on the other not

Comment: Which Magento version are you using ?

Comment: it's Magento 2.2.5

Answer (score 0):

**For fix Customer login issue in multiple browser change "Share Customer Accounts" to "Global"**

**Follow below path in admin:**

> Admin >> Stores >> Configuration >> CUSTOMERS >> Customer
>   Configuration >> Account Sharing Options >> Share Customer Accounts to
>   "Global"

Let me know if any issue.

Hope it help!

Comment: it doesn't work, the issue is still here

Comment: Try to flush cache run this command:
php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: I already emptied the cache. even with the cache off (php bin/magento cache:disable)  the issue is persistent

Comment: Okay. Then you can debug you issue to disable all third party and custom created module. And then check.

Comment: Try to disable all external module, set the default theme.... nothing the issue is still here...

I re-install a clean version of Magento Without external code I got the same issue...

Comment: It seem's that is a server issue, on my console I've got this error : Error parsing header X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block, 1; mode=block: expected semicolon at character position 13. The default protections will be applied.

Comment: Issue has fixed ?