# Unwanted url is coming with magento2 site url

Tags: magento2, url

Whenever I open my website it opens with an unwanted URL like

> **`www.mysite.com/?SID=gjc3knlipsmuhsbc73j0is36h2`.**

It should open like

> **`www.mysite.com/`**

Why this type of URL is coming. And when I clear cache, then site opens with normal url, but after some time same problem. Please tell me permanent solution of this problem.
Thanks

Comment: duplicate of https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/147373/49732

Answer (score 5):

Please follow this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147373/how-to-remove-sid-session-id-from-url-in-magento-2), you can remove that from admin panel on follwing path.

> **Go to the Store > Configuration > General > Web > Session Validation
>   Settings > Use SID on Storefront and set its value to No**
>
> The SID is a "session ID". Magento uses this to track a user's
>   activity within the same Magento installation. Normally, Magento
>   powers one website and one store from one installation (database).
>
> Magento could power multiple websites with multiple stores from one
>   installation though. The SID allows users to stay logged in while
>   navigating across these websites/stores.
>
> I think if you have the function enabled, the SID is sent when
>   accessing catalog URLs so Magento can update the session with the
>   user's location/state for the current website/store.
>
> If you're not running a multi-website or multi-store environment, it's
>   safe to disable the SID on the frontend.

[image]

Comment: if i set it to No then will it not effect to my site, i mean any problems with my site..??

Comment: no it will not affect your site

Comment: sure.. i will definitely do this if once my problem get solved..

Comment: it still coming

Comment: Flush caches try again and test in private browser or remove browser caches also.

Comment: yes i have done these all things.. but same result

Comment: Sorry , but not idea because basically with this changes that should be applied.

Answer (score 3):

I was facing same issue in Magento-2.1.9 and setting `Use SID on Storefront` to `No` doesn't work for me because I have set "`Auto-redirect to Base URL`" to "`Yes`".
I have resolved the issue by doing following.
If you are using single store mode, then copy file **vendor/magento/framework/Session/SidResolver.php** to l**ib/internal/Magento/Framework/Session/S
idResolver.php** and **change `protected $_useSessionInUrl` to `false`**